# Почему кортеж Python не принимает int при создании его через функцию tuple?

Tags: python, кортежи

Если объявить кортеж с помощью функции tuple()

```
some_tuple = tuple (1,)

print(type(some_tuple))
```

то возвращает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    
some_tuple = tuple(1,)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

В то время, как объявление кортежа без функции (литерально)

```
some_tuple = (1,)
```

работает без нареканий.

Comment: Потому что аргументом tuple как функции должен быть итерируемый объект, просто передача целого числа не поддерживается.

Comment: Вообще, похоже, что итерируемые встроенные типы по имени типа могут создаваться только из итерируемых объектов: например, list из tuple, tuple из list, tuple из dict, list из dict, с некоторыми ограничениями - dict из list или tuple (должна быть итерируемая последовательность из пар объектов). Нельзя просто вызвать `tuple(1)` или `list(1)` или `dict(1)` или `iter(1)`. (возможно немного криво сформулировал, но смысл примерно такой)

Comment: А, ну bytes немного отходит от этого "принципа", и ведет себя довольно неочевидно: `bytes(N)` создает не один байт с кодом N, а N нулевых байтов.

Comment: Благодарю вас )

Answer (score 1):

```
(1,)
```

Это уже готовый кортеж, согласно синтаксису языка Питон.

```
tuple (1,)
```

А тут мы вызываем конструктор класса `tuple`, сигнатура которого выглядит так (можно посмотреть через `help(tuple)`:

```
tuple(iterable=(), /)
```

Получив вместо чего-то, что можно было бы проитерировать, число, питон и выдаёт ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_tuple = tuple((1,))
# тоже самое
some_tuple = (1,)
some_tuple = 1,

print(type(some_tuple))
```

потому что tuple принимает один аргумент и он должен быть итерируемым.